# Log4J - Is there any point in explicitly specifying the class name in the call to LogManager.getLogger()?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm working on some legacy code with a lot of code like

```
private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ThisClassName.class);
```

I'm wondering if there is any advantage to typing out "ThisClassName.class" as opposed to

```
LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
```

As far as I can tell, there is none, but I'm wondering if there are any negative ramifications to using getClass().  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're making the `Logger` `static`, you can't use `getClass()`.

Answer (score 6):

Also, getClass() will obscure the actual class if there's a subclass that's actually invoking the method. For example, assume that in class A, method X, you call log.debug() and class B extends class A, overwriting method X, but calling super.X at some point. The log file will show class B, not class A.

Comment: Really? The logger is final and the class is passed to it at initialization, so I don't see why it would make a difference.

Comment: (Not necessarily saying you're wrong, just saying I think maybe you should double-check. I don't have log4j handy, so I can't test it.)

Comment: I believe that I've personally run into that before. It's been some time, though, because I gave up that particular practice after that.

Answer (score 2):

getClass() does not work from a static context. ThisClassName.class works for static and instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually use the `getClass()` version with an instance-variable `Logger` (you aren't *creating* another logger instance, merely looking one up).

The reason for this is that in class hierarchies, it can be useful to know what the actual type is of thing you are dealing with, even if logging is occurring from within a method on the superclass.

Normally a simple textual search will give you exactly what log statement is being called anyway, so I haven't found it confusing in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Other posters have already commented that getClass won't work if you want to define a `static` Logger - and defining one per-instance is inefficient.

If you want the correct class inferred at run time, and you are using at least Java 5, take a look at [log5j](http://code.google.com/p/log5j/), which wraps log4j in a Java 5 API.

This lets you write things like:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger();
```

and even:

```
log.debug( "This thing broke: %s due to bar: %s on this thing: %s", foo, bar, car );
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought they would have to be doing something funny with generics to allow "Logger.getLogger();". Turns out they're doing exactly what I implemented for my own project's log manager: create an Exception and read the stack trace. Still, it does make me feel that I'm doing something legal. :)